# CSS - Sliding in text

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui, css-animations

I have a website an I am trying to replicate the 'sliding in' of text as shown here:

```
https://tictail.com/
```

When the user starts to scroll, the text on that page slides in from the left.

I've tried taking a look at the JavaScript files that are being loaded but no use.

My application is using AngularJS, so it would be nice to stick with this librabry, rather than having to us jQuery and jQuery ui.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using this plugin.

Is really easy to import, just a CSS file and .js file.

http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/